# Match component to string for Dynamic component

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to dynamically create a child component, like here: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

That works quite well, my problem is, that I need a Type to use the ComponentFactoryResolver.

No I would like that to be very extensible and I'd like support any Component that sub-classes my abstract base class.
I want to have an optional router param, i.e. a string, to map to the Component (or a fallback).

Now I tried to inject a list of {name: string, ctor: Type} into my host component. I tried that with the 'multi' option:

```
Providers: [{
        provide: EditModalRef,
        useValue: {ctor: EditmodalComponent, name: 'DefaultEditModal'},
        multi: true
    },
    {
        provide: EditModalRef,
        useValue: {ctor: UserEditModalComponent, name: 'UserEditModal'},
        multi: true
    }]

// Then in my host component:
constructor(private editModals: EditModalRef[]) {
```

...that doesn't work: "NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[EntityComponent -> Array]"

Is there a more elegant way than having a provider with 'useValue' and a list of all the components?
Is there no way to inject a list of all classes sub-classing some base class like in Spring? (I'm coming from the backend).

Basically, I'd like my Users to just declare their components in 'entryComponents' of the root module and match those to a string.

EDIT: Oh man... after hours of searching I post this, ten seconds later I find out that I need to add `@Inject(EditModalRef)` to the injection site... Still leaving the question open for now, as I'm looking for a more elegant, 'DRY' solutiong - I don't want to add the component in five different places, like 'entryComponents', 'declarations' and also in 'providers' with the name as string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, no real way around it: all Angular components *must* be imported/declared in their respective parent modules, and dynamic components *must* be further identified as `entryComponents`, or the transpiler doesn't know what to do with them (though depending on what *you're* trying to do you may be able to cut out the `providers` declaration).

They're a little old, but Angular-In-Depth has some good material on using Angular's DCL:

1. [Here is what you need to know about dynamic components in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e);
2. [Dynamically Loading Components with Angular CLI](https://blog.angularindepth.com/dynamically-loading-components-with-angular-cli-92a3c69bcd28)

Comment: Yes, I thought so, but the additional step of declaring a provider just for the Type-Constructors... I thought maybe there is some programmatical way to read the "entrycomponents" array at runtime, but I haven't found a way.